# Localize button from a window

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

probably is a stupid question but i really don't know now, what i have to do to localize a button in a window i just redefined and create. I
 use extjs 4.2.1 and i produce a kind of mvc but is more similar to the old way of use this type of framework.

I have to define a window that have two buttons 'submit' and 'close' like this:

```
Ext.define('newWindow',{
    extend:'Ext.window.Window',

    config: {
        submitFn:function(){return null;}
    }
    bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px 5px 0',
    layout:'fit',
    width:460,
    height:390,
    plain: false,
    border:false,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: [{
        text:'submit',
        handler: function(){this.up.up.submitFn()},
        tabIndex:1000
    },{
        text: 'close',
        handler: function(){
            this.up().up().hide();},
        tabIndex:1001
    }]
})
```

When i create this window in my code i want to pass him a function to handler his behave but i can't..
i try to put him itemId, id but Ext.getCmp(id), Ext.ComponentQuery.query(id) doesn't do their job.

RE-EDIT:

OK the question isn't clear: I define in that way the components newWindow.
I say i don't use the mvc pattern and in a part of my program i create this component in like here;

> var dlg = Ext.create('newWindow', {submitFn: submit});

Where submit is the function i need to call to submit the value present in the window, with her logic.
This is what i need to do but i ask all another way to do that.

Comment: The `fmt:message` tag is not something from ExtJS... You know that, right? Now, can you show the function call you want to make, if you can get a reference to the button (what you are apparently trying to do with `Ext.getCmp`?

Answer (score 0):

You could always just set the window's [config](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-closable) `closable:true` instead of defining your own button.

Comment: I don't think this is answering the question, he also needs a submit button, and maybe other things to do in the controller

Comment: Probably stepped over the line, but your answer still doesn't answer the question at all, it doesn't make any sense as to why someone up-voted it.

Comment: @cclerville yes i can but i need to implement this kind of interface with a window with two button in the bottom. I know is redundant but i have to do my job in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I assume all the ways you have tried to get a reference to the button didn't work because the button wasn't created when you called them. You should either wait for the button to be rendered when calling `Ext.getCmp` or use `this.control` in your controller `init` method. Here is an example:

```
Ext.define('myController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    init: function() {
        this.control({
             '#submitButton': {
                 click: this.onSubmitButtonClick
             }
         });
     },

     onSubmitButtonClick: function() {
         console.log('Click');
     }
});
```

[And here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amitaviv99/XxSa4/)

Comment: i don't use controller because i don't use extjs mvc pattern. thanks anyway.